# Click the Link to Approve the Request Form

Tags: vb.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm writing an approval system. In the approval system requester need to request to approve the request application. After the requester fill up the information and send the application to manager via email. The manager just need to click the link to view the application and approve the application. Now, I'm stuck to do the code for click the link for approve. Anyone Please give suggestion or code to continue my project. Thank you.

```
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    mail.[To].Add(AppMgr.SelectedValue)
   'mail.To.Add("man@celestica.com")
    mail.IsBodyHtml = True


    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    'Or Your SMTP Server Address
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("YourGmailID@celestica.com", "YourcelesticamailPassword")
    'Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Send(mail)
```

Above is the code about send email to manager. Please help.

Comment: Your link should include GET parameters that would load the appropriate request that needs to be approved.  Please provide further details regarding what problem you are having.  As it stands, your question is not very specific.

Comment: Try using port 587: smtp.Port = 587